# Contrasting data in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to draw contrasts. I've used the following script

```
contrast <- makeContrasts(tam=("GSM151013-GSM150949"), ("GSM151014-GSM150950"), ("GSM151016-GSM150951"), ("GSM151019-GSM150953"), ("GSM151025-GSM150954"),levels=design)
```

'design' is as follows

```
      tam              tamless

GSM151013   0                   1

GSM151014   0                   1

GSM151016   0                   1

GSM151019   0                   1

GSM151025   0                   1

GSM150949   1                   0

GSM150950   1                   0

GSM150951   1                   0

GSM150953   1                   0

GSM150954   1                   0

attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$f
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

when I run the code I receive the following error:

```
Error in eval(ej, envir = levelsenv) : object 'GSM151013' not found
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: make sure `GSM151013` is in your current environment. You can do that with `ls()`

Comment: Can I just specify the row and column?

Answer (score 0):

You might have syntax problem.

Try this:

```
design <- c('GSM151013', 'GSM150949', 'GSM151014', 'GSM150950', 
            'GSM151016', 'GSM150951', 'GSM151019', 'GSM150953', 
            'GSM151025', 'GSM150954')

makeContrasts(GSM151013-GSM150949, GSM151014-GSM150950, GSM151016-GSM150951, 
              GSM151019-GSM150953, GSM151025-GSM150954, levels=design)
```

Comment: Glad it worked. @daedalus Mark the answer as accepted